# insert values in mysql with bash script

Tags: mysql, bash

How can i connect to my db and execute the query in bash

this is my code so far:

```
echo "estacion: "$st;
fcha=$year2"-"$month"-"$day;
echo "fecha: "$fcha;

echo $archivoF " ==> " $rutabase"datos/obs/"$st"/"$year2"/"$archivoF;
if [ ! -d $rutabase"datos/obs/"$st"/"$year2 ]; then
  mkdir -p $rutabase"datos/obs/"$st"/"$year2;
fi
mv $archivoF $rutabase"datos/obs/"$st"/"$year2
IFS='.' read -ra tipoO <<< "$archivoF"
tipoOb=`echo "."${tipoO[1]}"."${tipoO[2]}`
query="insert into FILES (name,type,date,station) VALUES($archivoF,$tipoOb,$fcha,$st)"

echo $archivoG " ==> "$rutabase"rinex/nav/"$st"/"$year2"/"$archivoG;
if [ ! -d $rutabase"datos/nav/"$st"/"$year2 ]; then
mkdir -p $rutabase"datos/nav/"$st"/"$year2;
fi
mv $archivoG $rutabase"datos/nav/"$st"/"$year2
IFS='.' read -ra tipoN <<< "$archivoG"
tipoNa=`echo "."${tipoN[1]}`
query="insert into FILES (name,type,date_f,station) VALUES($archivoG,$tipoOb,$fcha,$st)"
```

any suggestions

Comment: `mysql <options> -e "query string"`

Comment: Make sure you quote the values that are strings.

Comment: Why do you use `echo` in your assignments? Just `tipoOb=.${tipoO[1]}`

Comment: It's also not necessary to keep starting and ending quotes. `mv $archiveOF "${rutabase}datos/obs/$st/$year"`

Comment: i'll keep in mind your suggestions, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To execute a query from a script, use the `mysql` command with the `-e` option.

```
query="insert into FILES (name,type,date,station) VALUES('$archivoF','$tipoOb','$fcha','$st')"
mysql -h dbhost -u dbuser -ppassword dbname -e "$query"
```

Make sure you put quotes around the values that are strings in the query.